# How to join a coherence cluster

Tags: oracle, oracle-coherence

I am having trouble trying to access/join an external coherence cluster.
In my current project I have a server (not localhost) which is running a coherence cluster, and I need to join that cluster to get data from that cache.

I am trying this simple code, but it keeps creating a coherence in my own machine (localhost)

```java
public static void main(String[] args){

    XmlElement opConfig = XmlHelper.loadFileOrResource("C:\\Users\\916001\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\testAppProject\\src\\main\\resources\\tangosol-coherence-override.xml", "ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SERVER");
    NamedCache coherenceCache = CacheFactory.getCache("osbhmlmensage");
    System.out.println(CacheFactory.getCluster());
}
```

What I am expecting from this is loading "opConfig" and then access the cluster by using the "CacheFactory.getCache"

In tangosol-coherence-override I put this:

```xml
<unicast-listener>
  <socket-provider system-property="tangosol.coherence.socketprovider"/>
  <reliable-transport system-property="tangosol.coherence.transport.reliable"/>
  <well-known-addresses>
    <socket-address id="1">
      <address system-property="tangosol.coherence.wka">xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</address>
      <port system-property="tangosol.coherence.wka.port">yyyy</port>
    </socket-address>
  </well-known-addresses>      
</unicast-listener>
```

where in address I put the server's IP and the port I put the cluster's port

I am very new to oracle coherence cache and I am currently using Coherence 3.7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read configuration with `XmlHelper.loadFileOrResource`, but you doesn't use it anywhere. You should call `CacheFactory.setCacheFactoryBuilderConfig` with this configuration as an argument prior to creating named cache:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){    
    XmlElement opConfig = XmlHelper.loadFileOrResource("C:\\Users\\916001\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\testAppProject\\src\\main\\resources\\tangosol-coherence-override.xml", "ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SERVER");

    // here configuration is used
    CacheFactory.setCacheFactoryBuilderConfig(opConfig);
    NamedCache coherenceCache = CacheFactory.getCache("osbhmlmensage");
    System.out.println(CacheFactory.getCluster());
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much! I almost forgot that I have asked here. We just solved this without Coherence, it was just too much for such small porject